# bash-compl and bash-completion: no such file or directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, bash-completion

Whenever I open a terminal, the following errors pop out instantly:

```
bash: /usr/share/bash-compl: No such file or directory
bash: etion/bash_completion: No such file or directory
```

Also, when I try to compile my ~/.bashrc I get the same errors.
What should I do?

P.S. (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Comment: Remove an offending newline from one of your dot-files. `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` is supposed to be one command, not two.

Comment: take a look at `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`, there might be a extra newline.

Comment: check /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh, there should be a line there like this:             # Source completion code.
            . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion

Path to file in yours seems to be broken in two lines or has a whitespace in it, judging by the error

Comment: @Amadan where should I find this new line?

Comment: It is not a new line. It is a typo in one of your initialisation files; `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, or possibly (if you were extra naughty), the file rAlen suggested - `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`.

Comment: @ Amadan, georgexh, rAlen Thanks everyone! got fixed!!
The new line was in bashrc; Finally found it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a newline in ~/.bashrc which caused the breaks in those lines. Removing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps worked for me:

- Go to `/etc/skel` and do `ls -a`.
- Locate `.bashrc`.
- Copy that or open it with any editor and copy it to the home `.bashrc` file.